# find out name of terminal device emacs was started from

Tags: terminal-emacs

When I am running Emacs from a terminal, how do I find out the tty device name from inside Emacs?

I first thought that it can be done with `M-x shell-command RET tty RET`, but this does not work: instead of, e.g., `/dev/tty1`, I get `not a tty`.

Comment: I found the `(terminal-name) ; => "Mac` function by searching for `terminal` with `C-h f`, I'm not sure if it is related, I don't know what's the meaning of "tty" and "terminal". `M-x shell-command`, `M-x shell` and `M-x ansi-term` don't use the same "terminal" as emacs itself, so running the `tty` command inside emacs won't work. When I run emacs from a terminal emulator , `(terminal-name) ; => "/dev/tty"`, but the `tty` command outputs `/dev/ttys000`.